# How to store data initialized in Lua?

Tags: c, lua

I code some C that calling Lua. there are three Lua file: *init.lua*, *redis_pool.lua* and *run.lua*. First, I initialized redis pool in *redis_pool.lua* (calling *init.lua*, and *init.lua* calling *redis_pool.lua*), and the *redis_pool.lua* seems like that:

```
    -- init.lua
    local redis_pool = require('redis_pool')
    redis_pool.init_pools()
    ...

    -- redis_pool.lua
    local redis_pool = {}

    function init_pools()
            -- init data in redis_pool
    end

    function redis_pool.get_pool(pool_name)
            -- return one of redis in @redis_pool
            return redis_pool[pool_name]
    end
```

after init, table `redis_pool` seems like that:

```
    redis_pool = {
            ['pool1'] = {pool_sz, pool = {...}}
            ['pool2'] = {pool_sz, pool = {...}}
            ['pool3'] = {pool_sz, pool = {...}}
            ['pool4'] = {pool_sz, pool = {...}}

            -- some other functions...
    }
```

Now, I think the table `redis_pool` is ready, then I calling *run.lua* in C

```
    -- run.lua
    local redis_pool = require('redis_pool')

    function run_func
            -- error, redis_pool['pool1'] is nil!!
            local pool = redis_pool.get_pool('pool1')
    end
```

I have initialized table `redis_pool`, but why it became `nil` while C call another Lua to access it?
Do I have to return the `redis_pool` to C stack, and pass it to the successive Lua accessing function?

---

**Update**

some of these C code:

```
    /* C code to call init.lua */
    int init_redis_pool(void) {
            int ret = 0;
            lua_State *ls = luaL_newstate();
            luaL_openlibs(ls);
            ret = luaL_loadfile(ls, "init.lua");
            const char *err;
            (void)err;

            if (ret) {
                    err = lua_tostring(ls, -1);
                    return -1;
            }

            /* preload */
            ret = lua_pcall(ls, 0, 0, 0);
            if (ret) {
                    err = lua_tostring(ls, -1);
                    return -1;
            }

            lua_getglobal(ls, "init_pools");
            ret = lua_pcall(ls, 0, 0, 0);
            if (ret) {
                    err = lua_tostring(ls, -1);
                    return -1
            }

            lua_close(ls);

            return 0;
    }

    /* calling run.lua from C */
    int some_func() {
            ...
            ret = luaL_loadfile(ls, "run.lua");

            ...
            lua_getglobal(ls, "run_func")
            ret = lua_pcall(ls, 0, 0, 0)
            if (ret) {
                    /* error here */
                    err = lua_tostring(ls, -1);
                    return -1;
            }

            ...
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the parts of the C code where you run the files.

Comment: @llmo Euro: Updated the C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two independent Lua states for initialization and usage:

```
/* C code to call init.lua */
int init_redis_pool(void) {
        int ret = 0;
        lua_State *ls = luaL_newstate(); // ls is a local variable
        luaL_openlibs(ls);
        ret = luaL_loadfile(ls, "init.lua");


/* calling run.lua from C */
int some_func() {
        ...
        ret = luaL_loadfile(ls, "run.lua"); // ls is another local variable
```

When you load `init.lua` and initialize the pool, the changes only apply to your *local* `ls` variable. When you access `run.lua` in another function, your previous Lua state is already closed and destroyed.

You need to share your Lua state variable between the functions. One way would be to create the state outside both functions and pass it to each function:

```
/* C code to call init.lua */
int init_redis_pool(lua_State *ls) {

/* calling run.lua from C */
int some_func(lua_State *ls) {
        ...
```

Comment: How to fetch these redis pools from the global(passed-in) `Lua_State` in another new `Lua_state`?

Comment: @coanor for what do you need the other state? You could store the objects somehow in C and then pass them on to another Lua state, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @llmo Euro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453654/how-to-pass-data-between-multiple-lua-statemulti-thread