# How to pass data between multiple Lua State(multi-thread)?

Tags: c, lua, redis

I initiate Redis connection pool in *redis.lua*, by calling from C, I got a `redis_lua_state`, this Lua state is global initiated once and other thread only *get* from it.

While there comes a HTTP request(worker thread), I need to fetch a redis connection from `redis_lua_state`, then new another Lua state to load other Lua script, and these scripts will use this redis connection to communicate with Redis, how to do this? Or how to design my Lua scripts to make it simple?

---

**Code Sample:**

```
    /* on main thread, to init redis pool connection */
    lua_State *g_ls = NULL;
    lua_State *init_redis_pool(void) {
            int ret = 0;
            g_ls = luaL_newstate();
            lua_State *ls = g_ls;

            luaL_openlibs(ls);
            ret = luaL_loadfile(ls, "redis.lua");
            const char *err;
            (void)err;

            /* preload */
            ret = lua_pcall(ls, 0, 0, 0);

            lua_getglobal(ls, "init_redis_pool");
            ret = lua_pcall(ls, 0, 0, 0);

            return ls;
    }

    /* worker thread */
    int worker() {
            ...
            lua_State *ls = luaL_newstate();
            ret = luaL_loadfile(ls, "run.lua");

            /* How to fetch data from g_ls? */
            ...
            lua_getglobal(ls, "run")
            ret = lua_pcall(ls, 0, 0, 0)

            lua_close(ls);
            ...
            return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Lua states are separate, then there's no way to do this. Your worker thread will have to initialize the Redis connection *and* do processing on it.

Comment: I think I can maintain a table that referenced to Redis pool, and pass the table to the worker's Lua state, within the successive Lua scripts, accept the table as a parameter.

Comment: @coanor: If that's a Lua table, you can't do that. Separate Lua states are *separate*. These Redis pools are Lua userdata, right? You can't pass Lua userdata across to different Lua states.

Comment: I mean maintain a table as `lua_pcall`'s return value, then this table's memory is in C space, then I pass the table to another Lua state, is it impossible?

Comment: @coanor: What part of "*If that's a Lua table, you can't do that.*" didn't you understand? Lua tables are never "in C space". They're always either on a Lua stack or in some table in a Lua state. Two different Lua states are completely separate and have completely separate data. You cannot pass Lua values from one state to another.

Comment: @ Nicol Bolas OK, I got it, I think I should init my redis connection in C. While in Lua, calling C function to operate Redis. Lua just do the data processing(parse, build-string, etc.), all storage related pass to C to handle.

Comment: It is not just data you need to share - there are also sockets. You need some mutual exclusion mechanism to share a unique socket across threads, and performance will suck anyway. You should open a redis connection per thread.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is to implement copying variables between Lua states on C side. I have done a similar thing in my ERP project, but it requires a bit of a hassle, especially when it comes to copying user data.

What I did was to implement some sort of a super global variable (a C class in my instance) system that's implemented as `__index` and `__newindex` of the global table, which is a proxy to default Lua global table. When setting a global variable, `__newindex` would copy that to that super global. When another Lua state would try to access that global, it would retrieve it from the same structure.

And then the redis connection could be a mutex locked shared, so when one state accesses it, the other cannot, for instance.

Of course there's the issue of accessing Lua default globals that you also have to take care of.

Alternatively, you can check out [Lua lanes](http://kotisivu.dnainternet.net/askok/bin/lanes/), if that's an option (I've no Redis experience, so don't know how open the Lua is, but I see that you have full access to C api, so it should work).